# Read text file with formating in PHP

Tags: php, lines, file-read

I have long file with text. I want to print it on my website usign php but when i use

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("som.log");
?>
```

It prints text without new lines, how can i fix this?

```
2016-04-14 19:42:30,894 - __main__ - INFO - [Network] not found ;O 2016-04-14 19:42:30,898 - __main__ - WARNING - Just define wa 2016-04-14 19:42:30,908 - __main__ - INFO - getting pid 2016-04-14 19:42:31,914 - __main__ - WARNING - [Server] Begin of loop #0 2016-04-14 19:43:45,616 - __main__ - INFO - [Network] not found ;O 2016-04-14 19:43:45,620 - __main__ - WARNING - Just define wa 2016-04-14 19:43:45,630 - __main__ - INFO - getting pid
```

Comment: Try `nl2br(file_get_contents("som.log"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing it on web page? Then you can use `<pre>` tag to show preformatted text. Like this:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
echo file_get_contents("som.log");
echo '</pre>';
?>
```